# How to create a Titanic Creature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates

The Monster Manual 2 gives us the Titanic template. This is a template that can be added to any medium or smaller animal or vermin. Among other things, it increases their size to Gargantuan.

The book states the following regarding the origin of such beasts:

> Titanic creatures are the result of powerful transformation magic as well as forces of nature gone awry.

Hence, my question: What kind of magic? What could a player (Or NPC) do to actually create a Titanic creature?

Comment: Any method by which a character can bestow the Titanic template onto another creature is deemed valid for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Or I guess other ways to get a medium or smaller animal to similar sizes.

Comment: Have you checked Deities & Demigods?

Answer (score 3):

There is no in-game mechanism to directly grant the Titanic template to a creature. You could try to grant it via *Wish* or *Miracle*, but even then it would probably fail, as it is too powerful of a request.

There isn't a way for a PC or NPC to grant this template to another creature without Epic or Divine powers, which are usually beyond what players can do. At least without trickery like using *Magic Jar* or some other cheesy tactic.

If you just want to "[get a medium or smaller animal to similar sizes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170656/how-to-create-a-titanic-creature/170834#comment457288_170656)" that's a whole other thing. The "simplest" way I can think of is with a custom magic item of continuous *Giant Size*, which could make a creature even bigger than a Titanic Creature, it would be very expensive though, as it is a level 7 spell and requires a high caster level to achieve the bigger sizes.

Comment: Turns out this was harder than I thought. Epic magic works, but that always works. *Polymorph any object* doesn't work because *alter self* forbids templates. However, although complicated, the *wish* spell may be most reliable method. (Guidelines exist—however poor—for using *wish* to change a creature into another (*Savage Species* 150).)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Using those rules *wish* could work, but it would require a lot of DM help. Also, this could fall under "epic powers" category, as the caster level required is equal to the ECL of the goal creature, in this case that would be 25+LA, which would require an epic or very optimized caster.
Also, it's not very clear what happens with experience points when using wish, a creature with ECL 25+LA would need at least 300,000 XP, I doubt wish would just magicaly cover that, the other rituals have a mechanic for this where the creature has to pay them.

Comment: O, yeah, a PC that's become a titanic toad or whatever probably isn't gaining class levels ever again! However, honestly, I hadn't even considered the idea of a *PC* becoming some kind of ultra-mega-fauna. ("Okay, now that Varque is Rabbitzilla Varque, let's go conquer Burgton City!") I was just thinking that those *wish* guidelines could be adapted for use on an NPC bunny or whatever to grant it the template titanic, the bunny's next level be damned. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Don't forget Pun-Pun. Surely he can do it with Manipulate Form?